linux shell ctrl-C doesn't work (using busybox)
I'm working on an arm64 system (Arm PL011) and I have ported linux 5.15.68 using u-boot-spl , busybox.
In the past, I could use Ctrl-C in the linux shell by entering
setsid cttyhack sh

But somehow it doesn't work now. And I also get an error:

can't open /dev/ttyAMA0


There have been some changes but I don't know what has made this change.

What's the output of ls -l /proc/self/fd/[012], ls -lL /proc/self/fd/[012] and ps -o pid,ppid,pgid,sid,tty,args?

What sort of hardware and console/terminal?

I solved this, I'll post soon. THank you!

Upon boot stdin, stdout, stderr are open on /dev/console, but it's not possible to do job control with that device file. The job of cttyhack is to find and open the actual tty device file /dev/console refers to (based on information in /sys/class/tty/console/active), but in my case the device file for the corresponding device was missing.
So I did:
mknod /dev/ttyAMA0 c 204 64

and then :
setsid cttyhack sh

Now Control+C works again. I got the hint from my old note and it said the major and minor number is 204 and 64, but the information can also be retrieved from /sys/class/tty/ttyAMA0/dev.
